# bootstrap-select fails when Looping through Object for Select Option

Tags: reactjs, express, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-select

I have the below JSON and I want to iterate through the object and get it as options in drop down select list bootstrap:

```
location = {
"1": "1234 E. Big Beaver Rd. Troy WI",
"2": "7340 Shoal Blvd.,Austin CA",
"3": "58 Executive Park, Irvine CA 92456",
"4": "710 rue de la Renaissance Pittsburg"
}
```

I am using bootstrap-select, ReactJS and ExpressJS. I want to create a select field using the above object. I don't know why it doesn't work in a form. I have a similar select field with similar JSON and it works.

Below is my code:

```
<div className="row">
<div className="form-group col-md-4">
<label>location:</label>
<select
value={this.state.location}
onChange={this.handleChangeLocation}
style={{ fontSize: 14, width: '750px' }}
className="form-control">
{ Object.entries(this.state.location).map(elem => {
console.log('elem: ' + elem);
    return ( <option value = {elem[1]}>{elem[1]}</option> );
                    })
               }
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

What do I need to modify in my render to be able to use both bootstrap-select and ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.prototype.keys` instead of `Object.prototype.entries` to iterate over properties. Also do not forget to add `key` prop on each option so React will know what needs to rerender:

```
Object.keys(this.state.location)
  .map(key => (
    <option key={key} 
            value={this.state.location[key]}>
            {this.state.location[key]}
    </option>
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I change the code as you suggested, but still I couldn't get the dropdown options on the modal. The dropdown select is still empty :(